# How can I download a PDF from S3 with Java?

Tags: java, pdf, amazon-s3

I'm trying different approaches and I still get this saying the doc type is text plain.

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

This is my code:

```
ResponseInputStream<GetObjectResponse> response = this.s3Controller.getFileFromBucket(BUCKET_NAME, "proforma");

BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/home/caterina/Descargas/proforma.pdf"));

byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int bytesRead = -1;

while ((bytesRead = response.read(buffer)) !=  -1) {
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}

response.close();
outputStream.close();
```

Comment: have you tried to cat or type the content from the console... it surely seems it will be a response body with some kind of error or the like. I do belive your s3client is not correctly configured or you've got a 404